# Why is there a Golden Gate Bridge and a road in "Star Trek: Picard" in San Francisco?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-picard

Why is there a Golden Gate Bridge and a road in *Star Trek: Picard* in San Francisco? What travels on this road? Shuttle craft with wheels?

[image: The Golden Gate Bridge as seen in ST:P]

Comment: Plus, you can see the [Cliff House](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cliff_House,_San_Francisco) in the background. I wonder if they serve [Gagh](https://www.startrek.com/database_article/gagh) there now.

Comment: It is probably there for sentimental reasons.

Comment: The bridge also features prominently in *Star Trek IV*.  However, due to the storms that engulf the Earth during the film, the bridge is empty of traffic, so it is not possible to determine what kind of vehicles in normally carries.

Comment: To be honest, it almost looks like it got re-purposed as a solar power field.

Comment: @A.bakkar - They put a glass roof over the roadway

Comment: Perhaps it's just an ancient monument/tourist attraction, like the Pyramids

Comment: @Buzz  The bridge was destroyed/badly damaged in DS9 when the Breen attacked Earth so it’s been rebuilt/repaired too.

Comment: There are also staircases in Star Trek: Picard (seen in one of the buildings at Star Fleet HQ). I thought steps would have been replaced by elevators and escalators by the 24th century.

Comment: In the real world [10 Oldest Bridges in the World](https://www.oldest.org/structures/bridges/) list its oldest bridge as being from around **1200BC**, so why should it be surprising that something like the GG bridge is still around after only a few hundred years?

Comment: What drives on them? Red Barchettas, of course.

Comment: @RobertF Or, more appropriately, [Anti-Gravity Boots](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Gravity_boot)

Comment: @PeterM Because the GG is steel, not stone, and considerably larger.  It requires routine maintenance, particularly because the zinc-based paint acts as a sacrificial anode, to fend off corrosion, or it will collapse.

Comment: -1 for the assumption that the only purpose of roads is cars.

Answer (score 24):

## Sept 2023 Update

It seems that the Golden Gate Bridge is mostly seen as some kind of monument. This is specifically discussed in Lower Decks, Season 3, Episode 1, Grounded:

> **Beckett Mariner:** The longer I’m off a ship, the more useless I feel! Like that, that big dumb red thing.
> **Admiral Mariner:** Beckett, you know that’s the Golden Gate Bridge.
> **Beckett**: Nobody drives anymore! Why do you need a bridge? This planet’s wack.
> **Admiral**: People like the bridge. I like the bridge.

Given that the argument between the Mariners was about something else they might have just glossed over the fact that the bridge is still used for other things, so this dialogue doesn't necessarily invalidate the older answers.

## Original Answer

You have asked three questions, I will go through them one by one.

### The Golden Gate Bridge is still there, there is no need to tear it down with no reason

We have seen the Golden Gate Bridge several times in *Star Trek*. I can't remember if we saw it in the future during "The Voyage Home", but we can see it clearly in *Discovery*'s episode "Such Sweet Sorrow":

[image: The Golden Gate Bridge as seen in Discovery]

You can see that it's covered with solar panels. Note that we don't know if these solar panels are still in use, they could be historical remnants the same as the bridge itself. There is no reason why this bridge, even if it's unused, should be torn down - it's an iconic landmark and will still serve as a monument even if it's no longer used.

### Nothing travels on these roads specifically

As you can see, nothing travels on that bridge because it's covered with solar panels. We don't know if they are still in use or if there was a point in the past where having them made sense (before the discovery of nearly unlimited energy sources such as matter/antimatter reactors), but they are there.

### There are roads because cars are still a thing.

Cars are still a thing in the future. And why wouldn't they? It's just not feasible to take a shuttle everywhere, and there are people who are afraid of beaming. Also, people might still be driving cars because they enjoy them.

Even though it's in an alternative timeline, we can see that Kirk drives a car, that there is something similar to a motorcycle and that there are even still hitchhikers. This all pops up in this video:

Comment: There is a reason why unused bridges could be torn down: Maintenance effort/costs.

Comment: @JanWindemuth - in the post-scarcity world of Star Trek, there will be plenty of people who will maintain the Golden Gate Bridge for fun.

Comment: Also, it's not any old bridge, it's an iconic monument. But in general, you are right. Related: These solar panels look awfully new and in good shape. If they are still in use, then why? If they aren't, who keeps them in good shape?

Comment: Those are both valid points, I just wanted to add this in general, as the sentence in the answer was generally about bridges.

Comment: There's also that taxi in *Picard*.

Comment: The panels appear to be *above* the lower roadway

Comment: I wasn't aware that there is a lower roadway, to be honest - so that bridge could even be still in use!

Comment: In the Producing Picard short about the show's VFX, it's explained (out of universe) that they added the solar panels to the bridge just to cover up all the cars from the modern-day source video.

Comment: There's not a lower level on the golden gate. The bay bridge has 2 levels and they are rebuilding segments that appear to be eliminating the levels. As for solar panels, how do we know that's what they are? Could they not also be some kind of self contained unit that either makes use of solar harnessing or simply looks similar? Yeah, seems far fetched, but sometimes people just design things to look sci-fi like and don't care to plan out every conceivable detail as though the city were real and had to function. I say they are just fancy looking machine things. Good enough for me.

Comment: Yes, the Golden Gate Bridge might be maintained as a monument long after it stopped being useful because it is a beautiful and much loved marvel of engineering. It was the longest suspension bridge in the world when it was completed in 1937, and still is the ninth. Ironically, many of those who saw it being erected preferred the earlier view of the Golden Gate without the bridge.

Comment: Yes, we saw it in "The Voyage Home"; the commandeered Bird of Prey almost crashed into it before ditching (presumably in the bay).

Comment: The Golden Gate Bridge is also seen in The Motion Picture, where the upper deck appears to be covered, maybe with solar panel structures. Blurry screen grab: https://imgur.com/a/xUD1V3E

Comment: @EdmundDantes Just as people today maintain and run vintage steam locomotives purely because they love them.

Answer (score 16):

As you can see from [*VOY: Endgame*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endgame_(Star_Trek:_Voyager)), the Golden Gate Bridge of 2394 houses some manner of *travel system*, comprising individual small cars traveling at high speeds inside a series of transparent tubes, possibly some kind of mass-transit facility.

[image: Gif of a crowd watching fireworks on the Golden Gate Bridge, vehicles move behind them]

[image: Gif of a crowd watching fireworks on the Golden Gate Bridge, vehicles move behind them, the same scene as the previous Gif but later on]

Answer (score 2):

### Trains on the bridge

I can't cite canon for this, but you can plainly see the "urban density" of the Marin Headlands and Sausalito, and you can bet if those are that built-out, the Presidio is denser still.  This creates a transportation choke-point.

The devil is in the deconfliction. Yes, air is 3-D, but you need a fair amount of space to deconflict traffic to such a focused destination.  Simply because wind conditions could hurl a vehicle off course, aside from other failures like those who like to hand-fly.   Transporters, well how much "airwaves" does a transporter take? Can you have unlimited transporters in a high-density space? I doubt it.

We've seen the pods traveling on the bridge's upper deck in the *Voyager* scene.  However such pods simply lack the density required to bring in hundreds of thousands of workers in the Starfleet headquarters and Academy complexes. (To say nothing of ordinary commuters *merely passing through* between non-Starfleet activities in the City proper and their homes in Marin, Sonoma and Mendocino counties).  A train that handles 1000 people every 4 minutes, that's the kind of thing you need. And that's an ordinary subway train today.

[image: A train seen on the Golden Gate bridge]

So we can safely infer something like that exists, either tunneled (though the Golden Gate channel is fairly deep, making that hard) or on the lower deck of the Golden Gate, as per [the original vision](https://www.bart.gov/about/history) for the BART system.

It may, in fact, be precisely BART.  The trouble with changing out a tunneled rapid transit system to a totally new technology like pneumatic tube or maglev, is **that transit system is *there for a reason*, and the reason doesn't take a holiday for a couple of years** while everything is rebuilt, debugged,  torture tested and shaken down. The community simply cannot bear the cost of taking the system down that long.   It isn't modernized **because it can't be**.  So those 24th century commuter trains may be using grav-mag grapples to float *above* standard old 5'6" broad gauge steel railroad track, but standard they may still be.  The upside is the [Historic Fleet](https://www.bart.gov/about/projects/cars) gets to [operate](https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2011/03/bringing-a-museum-object-to-life-the-john-bull-locomotive/72651/) from time to time.

Comment: Underground transit access in San Francisco is seen in VOY 2x05 "Non Sequitur", when Harry runs from security. This suggests large scale mass transit exists in the 24th century. Whether or not it crosses the Golden Gate Bridge is anyone's guess, but for tunnels crossing the channel that really isn't too far fetched of an idea when considering habitation domes on the floor of the Atlantic were being planned five years prior in TNG "Family".